# Is it possible to write an SQL statement that performs a select statement to look-up a foreign key and the inserts a record

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL Database.  In the database, I have three tables:

1. Users => User_Id, User_Name
2. Requests => Id, Request_Name, Request_Desc, User_Id (FK)
3. TempRequest => RequestName, Request_Desc, User_Name

What I would like to do is write a SQL statement that will do the following for every record in the TempRequest table:

1. Use the User_Name field to query the Users table for the User_Id
2. Add the User_Id from Step 1 to the Request_Name and Request_Desc fields and Insert into the Requests table.

Comment: You mean only one statement ? No store procedure, no java code ?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: Yes, ideally just a sql statment or sql stored procedure. I thought maybe merge could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple insert/select statement with a join:

```
insert into requests (request_name, request_desc, user_id)
select tr.request_name, rt.request_desc, u.user_id
from temprequest tr
  join users u on u.user_name = tr.user_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct query would be this:

```
INSERT INTO Requests(Request_Name, Request_Desc, User_Id) 
SELECT tr.Request_Name, tr.Request_Desc, u.User_Id
FROM TempRequest tr INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_Name = 'QueryUserName') u
ON tr.User_Name = u.User_Name
```

The above query would first filter the User and then add the User_Id with the Request_Name, Request_Desc and finally Insert into the Requests Table.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the User_Name = 'QueryUserName'

Comment: The derived table is completely useless. You can simply join `temprequest` to `users`. And the condition on `user_name` seems wrong.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor User_Name = 'QueryUserName' is for  "Use the User_Name field to query the Users table for the User_Id"